# Раннее/позднее средневековье

Tags: орфография

Какое из слов пишется с прописной буквы?

Answer (score 1):

В словарях нет единства. Лопатин предлагает писать Средневековье (историческая эпоха) с заглавной, Кузнецов в этом отказывает. Искать единую истину бессмысленно.

Я рискну предложить так: 
раннее, позднее средневековье - как культурный слой (нравы, обычаи и т.д.);
раннее, позднее Средневековье - как историческая эпоха (политическое утройство и т.п.);
Раннее, Позднее средневековье - как искусствоведческий термин (картины, архитектура, костюм).

Comment: Мне нравится. Логично и красиво!